# Need assisstance with adjusting my json format and corresponding javascript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

My project works with the following json and js code:

[image: json before changes]

[image: js before changes]

my goal is to make the project run the same but with the json formatted as the following:

[image: json after change]

I have adjusted the js code to this:

[image: js code after change]

but I'm getting the following errors:

[image: errors]

this file uses the data:
[image: js]
[image: js]

The project looks like this when it is functioning:
[image: project]

I'm sorry if this isn't enough to go off, I am really new at this and am very lost.

edit: was told to add these -
[image: get headings and labels]

Comment: Can you post the contents of `getLabels` and `getValues`?

Comment: Try data[0].mapped